# Customize Spring boot Kafka listener metrics

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-kafka, spring-boot-actuator

We have a microservice architecture on the project and we use Prometheus and Grafana for monitoring. The services are implemented using Spring Boot and the integration with Prometheus is through spring-boot-actuator.
There are some Kafka consumers in the project, and for each @KafkaListener spring is generating some metrics. Here is a sample of the Prometheus time series for the metric `spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count`

```
spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count{exception="ListenerExecutionFailedException", instance="192.168.100.4:8001", job="spring-actuator", name="org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0", result="failure"} 2
spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count{exception="none", instance="192.168.100.4:8001", job="spring-actuator", name="org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0", result="success"} 2   
spring_kafka_listener_seconds_count{exception="none", instance="192.168.100.4:8001", job="spring-actuator", name="org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0", result="success"} 4
```

`org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0` - doesn't give much info regarding the `@KafkaListener` method of interest.
Is it possible to configure more meaningful value for the name label of these metrics?

Answer (score 1):

Give the listener a meaningful `id`.

`@KafkaListener(id = "someId", ...)`

Note that, by default, the id will be used as the consumer `group.id`, unless you also specify `group`, or set `idIsGroup` to `false`.